# Improve pentaho table input step performance

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, apache-kafka, pentaho

I am using table input step to extract data from oracle database and load into Apache Kafka producer(output step) by doing some concatenation.It is taking nearly 6 min to extract 2 million rows(table containing 50 columns).By seeing its log i found table input step taking longer time.How can i improve the performance in table input step?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, the log may be misleading: if the ConcatField or Kafka fields are slow, then the Input table will be slow not by itself, but just because it is not able to send data to the next steps.

First check the suspected Input table is guilty: remove the ConcatFields and Kafka steps and replace them by a Dummy step. If it still takes 6 min, then it is pure Oracle DBA optimization.

Comment: Found the problem is with kafka producer step which make my table input slow. Can u suggest any idea to improve kafka producer step performance?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know enough about Kafka (which be the way is a plug-in by third party). My suggestion is to ask the question to SOF/apache-kakfa, mentioning the parameters you are using in the Kafka producer. You may be redirected to the Kafka configuration.